Error with RPA.Images.Get Pixel Color In Image keyword
I'm trying to use th RPA.Images.Get Pixel Color In Image keyword
I'm getting an error :
[FAIL INSIDE] TypeError: Point.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
When I use this robotframework code :
${Color1}=    RPA.Images.Get Pixel Color In Image  ${OUTPUT DIR}${/}selenium-element-screenshot-1.png  0

And I get the error :
[FAIL INSIDE] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getpixel'
when I use this code :
${Color1}=    RPA.Images.Get Pixel Color In Image  ${OUTPUT DIR}${/}selenium-element-screenshot-1.png  0, 0

screenshot1
screenshot2
I'm expecting to get the rgb value

first one fails because x and y are both required and you are passing only x. Second one fails because you are passing 0, 0 as x and its considered as string  and no y.   Robot Framework uses multiple spaces as separator.

Hello I tried that before. Same issue. See scrrenshots. Thank's.

After checking out the code within the rpaframeawork package, point should be provided as string without any spaces like this:
${Color1}=    RPA.Images.Get Pixel Color In Image  ${OUTPUT DIR}${/}selenium-element-screenshot-1.png  0,0

as get_pixel_color_in_image() calls to_point() which looks like this;
def to_point(obj: Any) -> Optional["Point"]:
    """Convert `obj` to instance of Point."""
    if obj is None or isinstance(obj, Point):
        return obj
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        obj = obj.split(",")
    return Point(*(int(i) for i in obj))

eg. use x,y syntax where x and y are actual numbers and no spaces in between.

not working because it's consider tne comma like a string : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getpixel'
